# Why am I receiving 'InternalServerError' when deploying in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure

I've created a free trial account for Azure DevOps, and am following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops-project/azure-devops-project-github) to set up a pipeline for my code.

When I get to the section called "Configure Azure DevOps and an Azure subscription", I click Done, and the deployment fails due to the error listed below.

```
{ 
    "id": "/subscriptions/1863e18a-81cd-49ca-aa56-dd29e09f7aa/resourceGroups/VstsRG-[REMOVED]-0b4b/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/Deploy_DevOps_Project_hello-world/operations/629ED8F75DE87BE8", 
    "operationId": "629ED8F75DE87BE8",
    "properties": 
     {
         "provisioningOperation": "Create", 
         "provisioningState": "Running", 
         "timestamp": "2019-09-03T21:44:36.1937569Z", 
         "duration": "PT15M53.2807456S", 
         "trackingId": "109e1d66-6d61-41c0-b67a-0dda7d8f74e4", 
         "statusCode": "InternalServerError", 
         "statusMessage": 
          {
              "code": "UnknownException",
              "message": "Unknown Exception", 
              "target": "<GetOrCreateBindPendingIdentity>g__ThrowWithTrace|7_0"
          },
         "targetResource": 
          {
              "id": "/subscriptions/1863e18a-81cd-49ca-aa56-edd29e09f7aa/resourceGroups/VstsRG-[REMOVED]-0b4b/providers/microsoft.visualstudio/account/[REMOVED]",
              "resourceType": "microsoft.visualstudio/account", 
              "resourceName": "[REMOVED]"
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried re-deploying? I got a few Internal Server Errors yesterday, and simply retrying the deployment fixed the issues.

Comment: Yes, the same error has occurred for the past three days, different times of day.